# ROS Time - time_duration is out of dual 32-bit range

Tags: c++, ros

I am developing an application that saves some data into other formats including `.bag` format. Therefore, I use [ROS code](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) to save into this format if desired.

When I run this program, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  time_duration is out of dual 32-bit range
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the piece of code related to the error:

```
ros::Time::init();
bag->write("point", ros::Time::now(), arr);
```

**Notes:**

- When I comment both of these lines, the code works without error, but of course I cannot save any .bag file this way.
- I tried to wrap these lines in a try/catch block, but I still got an exception, and this sounds weird for me (I tried try/catch(...) which shall catch any exception from the program).
- Also, when the program does not get into the if condition related to the .bag format, the program still craches. This is still weird for me as this way the code did not reach the ros code, so why does the application craches? I also tried to wrap the ros code in a if (false) block and run the application, it does work fine! Is this somehow related to the compiler?
- I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Kinetic version of ROS

Comment: 1.  Do use a debugger to learn the stack trace when the exception was thrown.  2. Do NOT use `catch (...)` ever.  3. Try separating the `ros::Time::now()` function call from the `bag->write()` function call.  Save the value in a named variable which you pass to `write`.  Even better, trace the value of the variable before calling `write`... using `cerr`, that way you can be sure that `ros::Time::now()` completed successfully.

Comment: The thing is the program crashes even if it does not reach these 2 lines, so I will not be able to debug that, but if I remove them, the program works successfully

Comment: Then it is even more important to use the debugger and find out where it is crashing.  Most likely you have undefined behavior elsewhere in the code, and the presence of this code changes your memory layout just enough that the UB causes a crash instead of just data corruption.

Comment: I am using ubuntu for compiling the code, is there any recommended debugger to use ?

Comment: gdb is a good choice if you don't already have a preferred debugger